# QFile has incomplete type

Tags: c++, qt, qfile

Trying to create a new QFile with

```
  QFile filename(file);
```

I keep getting the following error

```
error: variable has incomplete type 'SampleClass::QFile'
note: forward declaration of 'SampleClass::QFile class QFile;'
```

I looked it up and I have tried to fix it with `#include <QFile>` but I haven't managed to do that.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you add `QT += core` to your pro file ?

Comment: No, but I just tried that and I still get the same error

Comment: Maybe you forgot to include `<QTextStream>`?

Comment: I've only tried to create a `QFile` so far not using `QTextStream` yet

Comment: It looks as if you've forward declared `QFile` from *within* the `SampleClass` definition.  So when you try to use `QFile` the in your code the compiler finds the nested identifier `SampleClass::QFile` rather than `::QFile`.

Comment: Have you tried this : QFile filename(file.c_str()) ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your forward declaration is wrong. It should look like:

```
class QFile;
```

And it should be placed outside of any class or namespace.